# Firestore Set Catch Finally

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

How do I clean up resources after doing a Firestore operation, I want to use the "finally" block to close a dialog after saving the record but it complains it is not a function.
I been searching for the API reference but all I find is the few examples in the getting started section.

my code is something like this:

```
db.collection("posts")
.doc(doc.id)
.set(post)
.then(function(docRef) {
    //todo
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error saving post : ", error);
})
/*.finally(function(){
    //close pop up          
})*/
;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Native Promises in node 6 don't have a finally() method.  There is just then() and catch().  ([See this table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility), node is on the far right.)

If you want do do something unconditionally at the end of a promise chain regardless of success or failure, you can duplicate that in both then() and catch() callbacks:

```
doSomeWork()
.then(result => {
    cleanup()
})
.catch(error => {
    cleanup()
})

function cleanup() {}
```

Or you can use TypeScript, which has try/catch/finally defined in the language.

Comment: Thanks that answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

A then following a then/catch will always get executed so long as:

- IF the catch is executed, the code within does not throw an error (if it does, the next catch is executed).

```
db.collection("posts")
.doc(doc.id)
.set(post)
.then(function(docRef) {
    //any code, throws error or not.
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error saving post : ", error);
    //this code does not throw an error.
}).then(function(any){
    //will always execute.
});
```