# Preventing a Redux dispatch if an updateDoc() fails in Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I want to be able to make a dispatch only if a document in Firebase gets updated, I have two categorised error at hand, a Firebase error, and no connection error, in other words, how to know for sure that the `updateDoc()` has passed so I can make the dispatch to change the current state according to that update. If not, of course show an error on the UI, the issue here is I am passing the dispatch after the await function. If I were using mongo I would handle this in the response.

```
const handelColor = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {

    const updateData = async () => {
        const docRefCol = doc(db, 'collection', currentUser.uid);
        throw 'simulated no premission error';
        await updateDoc(docRefCol, { customColor: 'red' });
    };
    throw 'simulated no connection error';
    updateData().catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        alert(errorCode);
    });
    throw 'simulated faild updated data erorr';

    alert('dispatch to local state');
    //dispatch(addColor({ select: 'customColor', value: colors[e.currentTarget.value] }));
};
```

I did come up with the following solution but still I think I still can do better.

```
const updateData = async () => {
    if (!window.navigator.onLine) {
        throw { code: 'Please check your connection' };
    }
    const docRefCol = doc(db, 'collection', currentUser.uid);
    await  await updateDoc(docRefCol, { customColor: 'red' });
    dispatch(addColor({ select: 'customColor', value:     colors[e.currentTarget.value] }));
};

updateData().catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    alert(errorCode);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow this code (untested) to avoid redundancy in calling your `updateData`:

```
const updateData = async () => {
    if (!window.navigator.onLine) {
        throw { code: 'Please check your connection' };
    }
    const docRefCol = doc(db, 'collection', currentUser.uid);
    await updateDoc(docRefCol, { customColor: 'red' })
    .then(() => { 
        dispatch(addColor({ select: 'customColor', value: colors[e.currentTarget.value] }));
    })
    .catch((error) => { 
        alert(error); 
    });
};
```

For more reference, you can check this related [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389163/firestore-set-catch-finally) that also discusses what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Async with then Is usually not recommended.

Comment: Have you tried using a `try-catch` block? You can `try-catch` block instead of `then-catch` with the same logic with my posted answer.